# How to populate a GridView in a pop-up that is inside an UpdatePanel after a button click inside an UpdatePanel

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, gridview

I have a `GridView` which has an `ImageButton`. When clicked it runs a query and populate a `GridView` from the result (or it should:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" ID="TasksUpdatePanel" UpdateMode="Conditional">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:GridView ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="false" AlternatingRowStyle-BackColor="#EBE9E9" AutoGenerateColumns="false" OnSorting="yourTasksGV_Sorting" AllowSorting="true" ID="yourTasksGV" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" EmptyDataText="You currently have no tasks assigned to you" OnRowDataBound="yourTasksGV_RowDataBound" OnRowCreated="yourTasksGV_RowCreated" OnRowCommand="yourTasksGV_RowCommand">
            <Columns>
                <asp:HyperLinkField Target="_self" DataNavigateUrlFields="Task Detail" DataTextField="Task Name" DataNavigateUrlFormatString="" HeaderText="Task Detail" SortExpression="Task Name" ItemStyle-CssClass="taskTableColumn" />
                <asp:TemplateField>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:ImageButton ImageUrl="~/theImages/Dependencies.png" CssClass="gvTaskDep" runat="server" ID="btnShowDepend" CommandName="TaskDepend" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("Object") + "," + Eval("FK") %>' ToolTip="Click to view Dependencies" />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
              </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

`Object` and `FK` are from the original query which populates the above `GridView`.

Code behind:

```
protected void yourTasksGV_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CommandName == "TaskDepend")
    {
        string[] id = e.CommandArgument.ToString().Split(',');
        connString = @"";
        string objectid = id[0];
        string fkobjectid = id[1];
        string queryStringParent =
                           string.Format(@"SELECT
                                 CT.OBJECTID 'Object ID'
                                 ,LTRIM(RTRIM(CT.ATTR2739)) 'Task Name'
                                 ,UA.USERNAME 'Manager'
                                 ,CT.ATTR2941 'Task Start Date'
                                 ,LTRIM(RTRIM(CT.ATTR2812)) 'Status'
                                 ,CT.ATTR2752 'Due Date'
                                 ,CT.ATTR2757 'Completed Date'
                                 ,CT.ATTR2849 'Checked Date'
                                 ,LTRIM(RTRIM(CT.ATTR2847)) 'Checked Status'
                                 ,LTRIM(RTRIM(CT.ATTR2848)) 'Checked User'
                                 ,CT.FK2744 'Dependent Task'
                   FROM HSI.RMOBJECTINSTANCE1224 CT
                                 LEFT JOIN HSI.RMOBJECTINSTANCE1232 S ON S.OBJECTID = CT.FK2940
                                 LEFT JOIN HSI.USERACCOUNT UA ON UA.USERNUM = (S.FK2852 * -1)
                   WHERE CT.ACTIVESTATUS = 0 AND CT.OBJECTID = '{0}'", fkobjectid);
        string queryStringChildren =
           string.Format(@"SELECT
                                 CT.OBJECTID 'Object ID'
                                 ,LTRIM(RTRIM(CT.ATTR2739)) 'Task Name'
                                 ,UA.USERNAME 'Manager'
                                 ,CT.ATTR2941 'Task Start Date'
                                 ,LTRIM(RTRIM(CT.ATTR2812)) 'Status'
                                 ,CT.ATTR2752 'Due Date'
                                 ,CT.ATTR2757 'Completed Date'
                                 ,CT.ATTR2849 'Checked Date'
                                 ,LTRIM(RTRIM(CT.ATTR2847)) 'Checked Status'
                                 ,LTRIM(RTRIM(CT.ATTR2848)) 'Checked User'
                                 ,CT.FK2744 'Dependent Task'
                   FROM HSI.RMOBJECTINSTANCE1224 CT
                                 LEFT JOIN HSI.RMOBJECTINSTANCE1232 S ON S.OBJECTID = CT.FK2940
                                 LEFT JOIN HSI.USERACCOUNT UA ON UA.USERNUM = (S.FK2852 * -1)
                   WHERE CT.ACTIVESTATUS = 0 AND CT.FK2744 = '{0}'", objectid);

        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connString))
        {
            //Get Parent Task
            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(queryStringParent, connection);
            connection.Open();

            SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
            gvParentTasks.DataSource = reader; //not working
            gvParentTasks.DataBind(); //not working
            upParentTasks.Update(); //not working
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(fkobjectid) && fkobjectid != "&nbsp;")
            {
                // Call Read before accessing data. 
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    //ddlCli.Items.Add(new System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListItem(reader[0].ToString().TrimEnd(), reader[0].ToString().TrimEnd()));

                }
            }
            // Call Close when done reading.
            reader.Close();

            //Get Child Tasks
            command = new SqlCommand(queryStringChildren, connection);

            reader = command.ExecuteReader();

            // Call Read before accessing data. 
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                //ddlCli.Items.Add(new System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListItem(reader[0].ToString().TrimEnd(), reader[0].ToString().TrimEnd()));

            }

            // Call Close when done reading.
            reader.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

I have a popup which has a `GridView`:

```
<div id="popupDep">
    <a id="popupDepClose" title="Close Window">x</a>
    <h3>Parent Dependencies</h3>
    <div id="dvFirst" class="parentGridHolder">
        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="upParentTasks" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional" ClientIDMode="Static">
            <ContentTemplate>
                <asp:GridView ID="gvParentTasks" runat="server" AllowSorting="false" ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="false" AlternatingRowStyle-BackColor="#EBE9E9" AutoGenerateColumns="false" ClientIDMode="Static">
                    <Columns>
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="Task Name" HeaderText="Task Name" SortExpression="Task Name" ItemStyle-CssClass="taskTableColumn" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="Status" HeaderText="Status" SortExpression="Status" ItemStyle-CssClass="taskTableColumn" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="Due Date" HeaderText="Due" SortExpression="Due Date" ItemStyle-CssClass="taskTableColumn" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="Manager" HeaderText="Manager" SortExpression="Manager" ItemStyle-CssClass="taskTableColumn" />
                    </Columns>
                </asp:GridView>
            </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
    </div>
    <h3>Children Dependencies</h3>
    <div id="dvSecond" class="childrenGridHolder">
        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="upChildrenTasks" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional" ClientIDMode="Static">
            <ContentTemplate>
                <asp:GridView ID="gvChildrenTasks" runat="server" AllowSorting="false" ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="false" AlternatingRowStyle-BackColor="#EBE9E9" AutoGenerateColumns="false" ClientIDMode="Static">
                    <Columns>
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="Task Name" HeaderText="Task Name" SortExpression="Task Name" ItemStyle-CssClass="taskTableColumn" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="Status" HeaderText="Status" SortExpression="Status" ItemStyle-CssClass="taskTableColumn" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="Due Date" HeaderText="Due" SortExpression="Due Date" ItemStyle-CssClass="taskTableColumn" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="Manager" HeaderText="Manager" SortExpression="Manager" ItemStyle-CssClass="taskTableColumn" />
                    </Columns>
                </asp:GridView>
            </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
    </div>
</div>
```

JQuery which displays the pop-up:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#btnShowDepend").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        centerPopupDep();
        loadPopupDep();
    });
});
```

When I click on `btnShowDepend` image, the pop-up is displayed but nothing is displayed in the `GridView`. Also, because I am using an ID, if there are multiple rows only the first button triggers the pop-up.

How can I modify the code so that the pop-up is displayed with the `GridView` populated and for each button that represents individual row handles its own click?

Comment: is the .ready Function firing first prior to any of the query data calls being Invoked..? does it load the grid would be my first question.. and from there I would narrow it down and determine where in the process it is failing and or not yielding the proper results.. also I would highly suggest converting that Database query into a Stored procedure that takes advantage of Parameterized queries..very hard to follow such code in it's current state

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a class for the binding in sted of an id

ASP:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" ID="TasksUpdatePanel" UpdateMode="Conditional">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:GridView ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="false" AlternatingRowStyle-BackColor="#EBE9E9" AutoGenerateColumns="false" OnSorting="yourTasksGV_Sorting" AllowSorting="true" ID="yourTasksGV" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" EmptyDataText="You currently have no tasks assigned to you" OnRowDataBound="yourTasksGV_RowDataBound" OnRowCreated="yourTasksGV_RowCreated" OnRowCommand="yourTasksGV_RowCommand">
            <Columns>
                <asp:HyperLinkField Target="_self" DataNavigateUrlFields="Task Detail" DataTextField="Task Name" DataNavigateUrlFormatString="" HeaderText="Task Detail" SortExpression="Task Name" ItemStyle-CssClass="taskTableColumn" />
                <asp:TemplateField>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:ImageButton ImageUrl="~/theImages/Dependencies.png" CssClass="gvTaskDep btnShowDepend" runat="server" ID="btnShowDepend" CommandName="TaskDepend" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("Object") + "," + Eval("FK") %>' ToolTip="Click to view Dependencies" />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
              </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".btnShowDepend").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        centerPopupDep();
        loadPopupDep();
    });
});
```

Added the class btnShowDepend to the button, this enables the binding to Jquery. 
If you want to transfer an id you can add it as alt an get it by getting the .attr('alt')

Comment: I have the two arguments from `CommandArgument`. Is there anyway I can use that? I am transferring the `CommandArgument` to the `RowCommand` function which is using it inside the query. I would like to know how to populate the GridView now :) Thanks.

Comment: Set both in the buttons alt seperated by a ,

Comment: I got that part working :). Now to populate the GridView :/ Any idea why it is not populating?

Comment: You shoud convert the data from the reader to objects, binding to a sql-reader doesn't work. Convert it to a list<class> and bind that list

Comment: I put a breakpoint in the `RowCommand` function but when I click on the `ImageButton` the breakpoint does not hit.